# Finding proper divisors in c

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a function that finds the number of divisors of a number n, which are smaller or equal to a number k using recursion (in C programming language).

For example, (9,3) should return 2 since the only positive divisors of 9 that are less than or equal to 3 are 1 and 3.

Here's what I've tried but can't figure out why it's not working:

```
int divisors(int n,int k){
    int sum = 0;
    if (k==0){
        return 0;
    }
    else if (n%k==0){
        return sum++ + divisors(n,k-1);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

If anyone is able to help I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. I made a few fixes:

1. `k == 1` as a break condition is faster, although `k == 0` works fine.
2. The integer `sum` is useless.
3. When not counting, your thinking was almost correct. You should return `0` but for this specific case while keeping the function calculating the next ints (`recursion`). Therefore you should return `0 + divisors(n, k-1)`

```
int divisors(int n,int k){
    if (k == 1) return 1;
    if (n % k == 0) return 1 + divisors(n, k-1);
    return divisors(n, k-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not handling the resolution of the recursion properly
There is no need for a `sum` variable, instead you want to return the function call (or 0) in any case.

If you find a number so that `n%k==0` holds true, you want to return 1 + the results of the next case. However, if you then find a number that is neither 0, nor a match it will stop, instead of checking all numbers down to 0. Therefore adjusting your code in the following way will solve the problem:

```c
int divisors(int n,int k){
    if (k==0)
        return 0;
    else if (n%k==0)
        return divisors(n,k-1) + 1;
    else
        return divisors(n,k-1);
}
```